# RegisterTaskDefinition C++ Function returning AccessDenied or No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Tags: c++, windows

The Following is the code I am using to add the Schedule Program.It's giving Access Denied or No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

Tried with all the combination, Didn't help.

I Basically need to add the Schedule Program to the root directory from my application.

```
IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;
VARIANT varPassword;
varPassword.vt = VT_EMPTY;



 hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
    _bstr_t(wszTaskName),
    pTask,
    TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
    _variant_t(L"S-1-5-18"),
    varPassword,
    TASK_LOGON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
    _variant_t(L""),
    &pRegisteredTask);
```

Comment: What library is that?

Comment: I am using the C++ API provided by the Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381365(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am able to add the Schedule Program properly when tried running the application from command line.While running as a System service I am getting this error.